# How to use below closure variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on clouser in swift iOS, I have tried to create variable using clouser and add 2 clouser in single variable, variable declaration I did right, but I don't understand how to access it in my code.

here is the variable declaration.

`var multipleClouser: ((_ success: (Bool), _ failer:(Error) -> Void)?`

Comment: Typically this is spelled "closure"

Comment: have you read this info: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you meant callback, like

```
var multipleClouser: ((_ success: (Bool), _ failer: (Error?)) -> Void)?
```

and usage, like

```
multipleClouser?(true, nil)
```

or

```
multipleClouser?(false, SomeErrorHere)
```

set up like

```
multipleClouser = { success, error in
    if success {
        print("Done!")
    } else {
        print("Failure")
        if let error = error {
            print("\t with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, and how to handle it's callback?